# Insert with liquibase failing on H2 with Table not found during startup

Tags: h2, liquibase, liquibase-sql

I am using liquibase 4.3.3 to insert data to H2 DB using yaml changeset. But, when I try to start the server I get table not found while inserting even though the table exists. But, if I use the generated insert statement and disable liquibase and use spring.sql.init.data-locations to specify the sql file having insert SQL statement, this works. Can you please help me out with this weird problem?

Comment: Are the tables also created by liquebase?

Comment: No these are created via JPA

Comment: For h2 to insert data, you need to use data.sql file (put it under resources directory) with create table and then insert statements.